# $wpdb->insert inserting two rows in database

Tags: wp-query, customization, wpdb

Hi i am trying to insert data in database but $wpdb->insert insert two rows.

my code for insert data is

```
global $wpdb;
    $tablename = $wpdb->prefix . '<TABLE NAME>';
 for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($emails); $i++) {

                $data = array("post_id" => $post_id,
                    "user_id" => $user_id,
                    "email" => $emails[$i], 
                    "status" => 1
                    );
                     $wpdb->insert($tablename, $data);

        }
```

> size of $emails is 1 (if i am inserting one email id).

Where am i making mistake please let me know.

Comment: As far I know, `$wpdb->insert()` is intended to insert columns (one or more) in one row, you can not use it to insert data in two rows.

Comment: Please show more of your code, this one looks fine to me

Comment: i am trying to insert only one row but this function is inserting two rows into the database.

Comment: @M-R Just Edited my code please review it.

Comment: Have you tried pulling it out of the loop to make sure its not the loop?

Comment: but i have to perform this in a loop because emails can be one or more.

Comment: And i tried out of the loop also still inserting two rows.

Comment: 1) a `foreach` would be much cleaner. I have never (I think) had a reason to use the loop you have in PHP 2) The problem is in code not posted, probably. Where/how are you executing this. Can you post some context? 3) Are you absolutely sure that `$emails` looks the way you think it does?

Comment: i tried without loop with one email id too as a simple insert but still inserting two rows. :(

Comment: Where do you have this code? What action triggers it?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this

```
function insert_data_into_table () {
        global $wpdb;
        $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "your_table_name";

        //Check if table exists
        if($wpdb->get_var("show tables like '$table_name'") != $table_name) :

            //if not, create the table   
            $sql = "CREATE TABLE " . $table_name . " (
            (...)
            ) ENGINE=InnoDB;";

            require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php');
            dbDelta($sql);
        else:
          foreach($emails as $mail):
              $insert = "INSERT INTO  " . $table_name . "
                (post_id, post_id, email, post_id) 
                VALUES ($post_id, $user_id, email['content'], 1);"
              $results = $wpdb->query( $insert );
          endforeach;
        endif;
    }
```

I'm assuming that `$email` is an array containing some data? If you want to save the entire array, then you should `serialize()` the array.